# How do I unlock Altale's Extra chart?

Tags: deemo

As title. Deemo released its 3.0 update which introduces a new difficulty called "Extra". Altale has an Extra chart (LV S) according to [its wiki](http://deemo.wikia.com/wiki/Altale) and multiple videos on YouTube.

How do I unlock it? Does the Tree have to reach a certain height? Or are there specific things to click in rooms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Extra difficulty chart is unlocked by selecting the scroll on the piano in the Piano Room after reaching 30m Tree Height in playthrough 2 onwards (requires Forgotten Hourglass).